# Why CommandParameter passes the inverse value of CheckBox.IsChecked

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I would like to ask why `CommandParameter` passes the opposite value. as the event names' implies that the events (`Checked` and `Unchecked`) have fired and state of `IsChecked` should have changed, but that is not the case as if IsChecked were not assigned yet. It is not a big problem as I can assume the opposite all the time, but once I extends `Triggers` to include `DataTrigger` then, I am not be able to know whether `CommandParameter` is the inverse one or not!

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckBoxChecked}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ia:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LayoutManager.ShowZeroInv}" Value="Visible">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SameCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CheckBox}}, Path=IsChecked}" />
        </ia:DataTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SameCommand}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CheckBox}}, Path=IsChecked}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SameCommand}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CheckBox}}, Path=IsChecked}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

I have found a solution to work out with it as follow:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CheckBoxChecked}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ia:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="Visible">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SameCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CheckBox}}, Path=IsChecked}" />
        </ia:DataTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SameCommand}">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SameCommand}">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
                </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

but I wanted to know what is happening? Is it due to the fact that the state of `IsChecked` is not yet changed when the events are fired or is it because of something else?

Comment: I notice this long time ago, and I think your guess are right.

Comment: This looks like a rather large sledgehammer to crack a nut. Is there a reason why you just don't add some processing into the setter of your CheckBoxChecked property?

Comment: @Peregrine I wanted an explanation at the first place as it is an unexpected behavior. Regarding, CheckBoxChecked is not a direct property inside the ViewModel, but rather a property in a domain model. Having said that, now I was thinking that could have also subscribed to into the domain model's ProperyChanged event, but it wouldn't be practical as the domain model object might be reassigned anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I wanted to know what is happening? Is it due to the fact that the state of `IsChecked` is not yet changed when the events are fired ...

No. The `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` has been set by the time the `Checked`/`Unchecked` event is fired just as expected.

> ...or is it because of something else?

Yes, it's due to the fact that the binding is resolved before the event is raised. So the `CommandParameter` is set to either `true` or `false` based on whether the `CheckBox` is currently checked *before* you actually interact with the `CheckBox`.

Comment: thanks. so do you mean every time the event `Checked` or `Unchecked` is raised the binding is resolved right before it in a successive manner? so this why the first-time raised event (i.e., `Checked`) would result with a binding value of `false` as the default value of a boolean. the second time as `Unchecked` it would be `true`,...etc. right?

Comment: The binding is resolved when the XAML processor parses the CheckBox element. It is then updated whenever the bound value changes, but the command is invoked before the CommandParameter is updated.